# Reading Message from Kafka Topic and Dump it into HDFS

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs

I am trying to consume data from Kafka Topic, load it into Dataset and then perform filter before load into into Hdfs.

I am able to consume from kafka topic, load it into dataset and save as a parquet file in HDFS But not able to perform filter condition. can you please share the way to perform filter before save to hdfs?
i am using Java with Spark to consume from kafka topic.
some part of my code is like this:

```
DataframeDeserializer dataframe = new DataframeDeserializer(dataset);

 ds = dataframe.fromConfluentAvro("value", <your schema path>, <yourmap>, RETAIN_SELECTED_COLUMN_ONLY$.MODULE$);

StreamingQuery query = ds.coalesce(10)
                .writeStream()
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", path.toString())
                .option("checkpointLocation", "<your path>")
                .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                .start();
```

Comment: The answer from @Srinivas is good.I think we can learn [kafka-connect-hdfs](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) how works or use this lib.

Answer (score 1):

Write filter logic before `coalesce` i.e `ds.filter().coalesce()`

```
DataframeDeserializer dataframe = new DataframeDeserializer(dataset);

 ds = dataframe.fromConfluentAvro("value", <your schema path>, <yourmap>, RETAIN_SELECTED_COLUMN_ONLY$.MODULE$);

StreamingQuery query = 
                ds
                .filter(...) // Write your filter condition here
                .coalesce(10)
                .writeStream()
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", path.toString())
                .option("checkpointLocation", "<your path>")
                .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                .start();
```

Comment: let's say i have filter condition like this: Country='USA' and State='Texas', then the query like this ?: StreamingQuery query = 
                ds.filter("County=='USA' AND State='Texas'")
                .coalesce(10)
                .writeStream()
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", path.toString())
                .option("checkpointLocation", "<your path>")
                .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                .start();

Comment: sure Sri, i will modify the code as per your suggestion, will share the result :)

Comment: Filter condition worked as expected. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I would strongly recommend [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).
All you need is the HDFS Sink Connector, that replicates the data from a Kafka topic to HDFS.

- For HDFS **2.x** files you can use [HDFS 2 Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html)
- For HDFS **3.x** files use the [HDFS 3 Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/hdfs3/index.html#hdfs3-connector)